# fast query for too many tables in a database

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

For very very large tables, **indexing** may help quite a lot. But what is the solution for **too many small tables** in a data base. ?

what if I have a large DB, that has too many tables in it. how can i make query fast as indexes help fasten queries of a table?

Lets talk with a real example.
in stackoverflow.com , there is a table say. "**questions**".  having **id,date, votes.**           and then there exist **a table for each id** in the questions table.  (this table will have the name as of the numeric id . eg. "**q-45588**")    now its easy to **index  the "questions"** table. but what about **so many child tables of each question id**.  (that may contain  ids,answer 1, answer 2, answer 3, comment 1, comment 2... votes, down votes, dates, flags, so many things) ?

This is what happens in usual accounts software. ie. debtors account table having ids of all debtors and each table exist for each of that id (having further details of the debtor)

**or is it a design problem?**
**update** -----------------
Some people might say that do all in 3 or 4 tables (which may have **trillions** of rows)
e.g **questions table, answers table, comments table, users table.**

heres an example of modified stack

```
Catagory of thread:-----info----

Question
Discussion

Catagory of Thread Response:----info-----

A  Answer
c  comment


Theads:----A table-----

Id (key)
Thread Id number (Long data type)
status (active,normal,closed(visible but not editable), deleted, flagged, etc.
type (Ques / Dis)
votes Up
vots Down
count of views
tag 1
tag 2
tag 3
Subject
body
maker ID
date time stramp of time creation
date time stramp of time last activity
A  Answer count
c  comment count




Thread: (table name is thread id (long data type) (in Threads table)----A table-----

id (key)
response text
response type (    A  Answer / c  comment)
vote up
vote down
abuse count
```

Comment: Thanks for the plus one +1, who ever did it.

Comment: Denormalizing for performance is a real thing, but if you have thousands of tables, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: What is a "large database" ? Size only matters when your hardware doesn't match.

Comment: its a matter of fetching, not storing @FrankHeikens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, indexes are meant to make searching faster by providing and ordered structure to search within. In a very small table, since searching should be fast to begin with, it might not make much sense. Your best bet would be to try with and without indexes, and measure accordingly.

That being said, if your small tables have the same exact structure, it might make more sense (from a RDBMS point of view anyway) to merge them into a single entity.

Comment: Trillions of row might be a bit much. I'd probably start looking for alternatives to MySQL (and most RDBMS) as that point. See http://serverfault.com/questions/168247/mysql-working-with-192-trillion-records-yes-192-trillion for a few ideas on the subject.

Comment: A stronger version of the last statement, for emphasis: Having many tables with identical structure is a symptom of an inappropriate design. The number of tables in your database should not change as data is added to your application.

Comment: @TheVedge what strategy do you think stack is using in its postgresql db?

Comment: @duskwuff same for you too as above ^

Comment: Thanks in advance to your reply. (answer accepted with due honor given)

Comment: @TheVedge  I like your suggestion of you two a lot. I was thinking in an incorrect way before. further more would you like to share thoughts that for thread table. should i make seperate tables for questions and discussion  (same for one comment table or divide it to  types of comments like (citaion, counter question etc)      the thing is that all that has same catagory but different sub type

Comment: would only a questions table, a answers, users, and comments table be suffice?

Comment: Correct. One table per for each distinct type of data is generally appropriate.

Comment: @duskwuff iam surprised that if a user votes up/down for a post. its been remembered when the use returns after a week or year. where that should be stored ? in the user table or post table or somewhere else?

Comment: Where you have tables with very large numbers of rows, partitioning is often a help. Oracle partitioning is a pricey option on top of Enterprise Edition, itself a pricey option, but PostgreSQL partitioning is very usable and of course free (see my anser for description of use case and link). Don't know about MySQL

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a design problem. Having multiple tables with the same columns should set off alarm bells immediately -- having multiple tables with the same unique key should as well.

In the example you give you should have a single child table.

Now, in some cases you might have a table with one or more distinct values that represent a large proportion of the table rows. For example, let's say that you have sales for 50 customers but one of them is responsible for 40% of the total sales records with the others distributed evenly between the other customers. Accessing the smaller customers' data through an index on customer_id makes sense, but it does not for the large customer. In that case you might look at partitioning the table to place the large customer's records in one child table and the other records in another, both being related to a master table http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-partitioning.html .

However in general, and for your initial design, you should be using a single non-partitioned table for these child records.

Comment: ok. I would repeat this one too. "iam surprised that if a user votes up/down for a post. its been remembered when the use returns after a week or year. where that should be stored ? in the user table or post table or somewhere else? –" I deleted coookies and still it tells me that i voted 8 hours ago.

Comment: I think I'd store it in a table of USER_ID, POST_ID, VOTE, with vote being +1 or -1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this document can help you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-cache.html

Actually, MySQL and other RDBMSs are focus on handling a big table, not many tables, right? If you want to handle extremely large number of tables, you should consider about NoSQL solutions.